# Parse error in PHP? Error on line 4?

Tags: php

I am not sure what my parse error is? The html file linked to this file does have the proper file associated with it. I complete the html file form and it shows the proper path to my php file but gives me a parse error on line 4?

```
<?php
    $month = $_GET["month"];
    $color = $_GET["color"]
    $colorFortune = color_fortune($color);
    $fortune = yourFortune($month);

function yourFortune($month)
{
    if (strtoupper($month) == "JANUARY") {
        return "all of your New Years resolutions will come true!";
    }
    elseif (strtoupper($month) == "FEBRUARY") {
        return "you will fall in love with a special someone!";
    }
    elseif (strtoupper($month) == "MARCH") {
        return "luck will shine upon you!";
    }
    elseif (strtoupper($month) == "APRIL") {
        return "a golden egg of opportunity will fall into your lap.";
    }
    elseif (strtoupper($month) == "MAY") {
        return "never fear! The end of something marks the start of something new.";
    }
    elseif (strtoupper($month) == "JUNE") {
        return "the sun will shine on you if you let it.";
    }
    elseif (strtoupper($month) == "JULY") {
        return "you can’t steal second base and keep your foot on first.";
    }
    elseif (strtoupper($month) == "AUGUST") {
        return "you will be sharing great news with all the people you love.";
    }
    elseif (strtoupper($month) == "SEPTEMBER") {
        return "you have the power to write your own fortune.";
    }
    elseif (strtoupper($month) == "OCTOBER") {
        return "you will be successful in your work.";
    }
    elseif (strtoupper($month) == "NOVEMBER") {
        return "you will enjoy good health; you will be surrounded by luxury.";
    }
    elseif (strtoupper($month) == "DECEMBER") {
        return "you will make change for the better.";
    }
    else {
        return "Error: You didn't enter your birth month!";
    }
}

function color_fortune($color)
{
    if (strtoupper($color) == "RED") {
        return "Your ambitions will become real and ";
    }
    elseif (strtoupper($color) == "BLUE") {
        return "You will experience trust and loyalty in your life and ";
    }
    elseif (strtoupper($color) == "PINK") {
        return "You will experience unconditional love and ";
    }
    elseif (strtoupper($color) == "PURPLE") {
        return "Your creativity will shine through and ";
    }
    elseif (strtoupper($color) == "WHITE") {
        return "You will acheive a sense of wholeness in your life and ";
    }
    elseif (strtoupper($color) == "BLACK") {
        return "You will uncover a mystery of life and ";
    }
    elseif (strtoupper($color) == "ORANGE") {
        return "You will meet new people that will bring otimism to your life and ";
    }
    elseif (strtoupper($color) == "GREEN") {
        return "You will find a four leaf clover that will bring you luck, balance, growth, and ";
    }
    elseif (strtoupper($color) == "YELLOW") {
        return "You will learn new skills that will help you advance in your career ";
    }
    else {
        return "I don't know that color! But, ";
    }
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<title>Your Fortune</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1><?php echo $colorFortune . $fortune; ?></h1>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: don't believe everything PHP says; it's not on *that* line.

Comment: Line 3: `$color = $_GET["color"]    //missing ;`

Comment: Thank you! That was a big part of the problem. I was staring at line 4 thinking what is wrong with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$color = $_GET["color"]
```

missing `;`

Comment: I feel like a dumb dumb! Thank you!!!

Comment: Eh. Happens to everyone now and then.